# Conversion Tracking in Google Analytics with Google Sign-In

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

We implemented the possibility to sign up and sign in with your Google Account on our single page app. We already have full conversion tracking in place, but now we see all conversions come from accounts.google.com / referal. Furthermore, I would like to track the sign ups and sign ins in Google Analytics.

1. Putting accounts.google.com on my referal exclusion list should solve the problem with not seeing the correct source of the session, right?
2. Is there a possibility to send events to Google Analytics when a visitor uses the sign up / sign in button on my website?

Best regards,
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

1. yes, this would solve the problem. However, this would take effect only on the data collected after the referral exclusions settings were updated.
2. this only depends on your particular implementation. Usually, you may add all the necessary tracking with your site code.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much!

1. Is there anything I need to consider when I put accounts.google.com on the exclusion list? Do you think there is any case which makes accounts.google.com a valid referral I need to know about?

2. Great, Thanks! I could not find anything on the Google documentation. May I ask, if you have an example for this or know about an article with an explanation?

Comment: 1. I don't think accounts.google.com could be a valid referral but this heavingly depends on your particular case

Comment: 2. Google for 'events traking' for your particular tracking inplementation. here is an example of event tracking with gtag.js https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events